# Is it possible to access the database from a service?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, background-service

I want to access the database from my service which runs in the background. Is that possible?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058107/service-accessing-a-database

Comment: so my database class should extend SQLiteopenhelper. Otherwise the service cannot access it right?

Comment: yes , please go through the Article http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: but i suggest you to use AsyncTask to access database in background instead of Service

Comment: does it has any advantage over service?

Comment: check this post :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957775/android-asynctask-vs-service

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to access your database from service. To access database, all you need is `Context` which is also available in service.

Comment: How to get Context within a Service?

Comment: @channae `Service` extends from `Context`, hence passing `this` or `YourService.this` to where ever it's required will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to access the database from a service. All you have to do is, create an object of the database class that extends SqliteOpenHelper, pass the ServiceName.this as the context or else use your application class as the context.

```
DbHelper db = new DbHelper(ServiceClass.this);
db.performOperations();
db.close();
```

OR

```
DbHelper db = new DbHelper(YourApplicationClass.getAppContext());
db.performOperations();
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, and whereever is a need of context use service's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a normal functionality which we Use in application. @Ajay is right.

[USE EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058107/service-accessing-a-database)

You can Call a method that access DB from your service class in thread which execute after some seconds.