# How to call SyncAdapter in android on a particular time

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-syncadapter

I want to call my sync adapter whenever I insert any contact value in my Sq-lite Database in my application

It will work fine whenever I do it manually in Account & sync section of Settings but I want to do it automatically whenever any contact is added to Sq lite database of my application.
I  have also followed this link [Android SyncAdapter Automatically Initialize Syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090604/android-syncadapter-automatically-initialize-syncing)for requesting a sync but its not working in my case.
Here is the code for my sync Adapter:

```
package com.example.phonebook;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.example.phonebook.Database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.example.phonebook.Model.Contact;

import android.R.string;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter;
import android.content.ContentProviderClient;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SyncResult;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * @author sam
 * 
 */
public class ContactsSyncAdapterService extends Service {


    private static final String TAG = "ContactsSyncAdapterService";
    private static SyncAdapterImpl sSyncAdapter = null;
    private static ContentResolver mContentResolver = null;
    private static String UsernameColumn = ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC1;
    private static String PhotoTimestampColumn = ContactsContract.RawContacts.SYNC2;
    static DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public ContactsSyncAdapterService() {
        super();
        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    }

    public static class SyncAdapterImpl extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
        private Context mContext;

        public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context) {
            super(context, true);
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
            try {

                ContactsSyncAdapterService.performSync(mContext, account, extras, authority, provider, syncResult);
            } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        IBinder ret = null;
        ret = getSyncAdapter().getSyncAdapterBinder();
        return ret;
    }

    public SyncAdapterImpl getSyncAdapter() {
        if (sSyncAdapter == null)
            sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapterImpl(this);
        return sSyncAdapter;
    }

    private static void addContact(Account account, String name, String username) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Adding contact: " + name);
        Log.v("name", name);
        Log.v("phonenumber", username);
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        builder.withValue(RawContacts.SYNC1, username);
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
        //builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME, username);
            operationList.add(builder.build());

        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.example.PhoneBook");
        //builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, username);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(Phone.NUMBER, username);

        operationList.add(builder.build());

        try {
            mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void updateContactStatus(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList, long rawContactId, String status) {
        Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
        Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor c = mContentResolver.query(entityUri, new String[] { RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, Entity.DATA_ID, Entity.MIMETYPE, Entity.DATA1 }, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                if (!c.isNull(1)) {
                    String mimeType = c.getString(2);

                    if (mimeType.equals("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.example.PhoneBook")) {
                        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.CONTENT_URI);
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.DATA_ID, c.getLong(1));
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS, status);
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_RES_PACKAGE, "com.example.PhoneBook");
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_LABEL, R.string.app_name);
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.StatusUpdates.STATUS_TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis());
                        operationList.add(builder.build());

                        //Only change the text of our custom entry to the status message pre-Honeycomb, as the newer contacts app shows
                        //statuses elsewhere
                        if(Integer.decode(Build.VERSION.SDK) < 11) {
                            builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
                            builder.withSelection(BaseColumns._ID + " = '" + c.getLong(1) + "'", null);
                            builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, status);
                            operationList.add(builder.build());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }

    private static void updateContactPhoto(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList, long rawContactId, byte[] photo) {
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = '" + rawContactId 
                + "' AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = '" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'", null);
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        try {
            if(photo != null) {
                builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
                builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
                builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, photo);
                operationList.add(builder.build());

                builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
                builder.withSelection(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = '" + rawContactId + "'", null);
                builder.withValue(PhotoTimestampColumn, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                operationList.add(builder.build());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class SyncEntry {
        public Long raw_id = 0L;
        public Long photo_timestamp = null;
    }

    private static void performSync(Context context, Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult)
            throws OperationCanceledException {
        HashMap<String, SyncEntry> localContacts = new HashMap<String, SyncEntry>();
        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Log.i(TAG, "performSync: " + account.toString());

        // Load the local contacts
        Uri rawContactUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name).appendQueryParameter(
                RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type).build();
        Cursor c1 = mContentResolver.query(rawContactUri, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, UsernameColumn, PhotoTimestampColumn }, null, null, null);
        while (c1.moveToNext()) {
            SyncEntry entry = new SyncEntry();
            entry.raw_id = c1.getLong(c1.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            entry.photo_timestamp = c1.getLong(c1.getColumnIndex(PhotoTimestampColumn));
            localContacts.put(c1.getString(1), entry);
        }

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
        try {
            // If we don't have any contacts, create one. Otherwise, set a
            // status message
            ArrayList<Contact> contacts=ContactsSyncAdapterService.databaseHelper.getAllContacts();
            Log.v("size of  contacts", ""+contacts.size());

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            String name=contacts.get(i).getName();
            String phone=contacts.get(i).getPhone();
            Log.v("contactName", name);
            Log.v("phone", phone);
            Log.v("image", ""+contacts.get(i).getImage());
            Log.v("size of local contacts", ""+localContacts.size());
            Log.v("size of local23 contacts", ""+localContacts.get(phone));
            if (localContacts.get(phone) == null) {
                addContact(account, name, phone);

            } else {
                System.out.println(localContacts.size());
                Log.v("phonenumber",""+ localContacts.get(phone));
                if (localContacts.get((phone)).photo_timestamp == null || System.currentTimeMillis() > (localContacts.get(phone).photo_timestamp + 604800000L)) {

                    //You would probably download an image file and just pass the bytes, but this sample doesn't use network so we'll decode and re-compress the icon resource to get the bytes
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
                    icon.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
                    updateContactPhoto(operationList, localContacts.get(phone).raw_id, stream.toByteArray());
                }
                updateContactStatus(operationList, localContacts.get(phone).raw_id, "hunting wabbits");
            }

            }
            if (operationList.size() > 0)
                mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);

            ContactsSyncAdapterService.databaseHelper.closeDB();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //ContactsSyncAdapterService.databaseHelper.closeDB();;
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}</p>
```

Please help me to short out this.If anyone can

Comment: You need to write a background Service which will checks your db new records continuously  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058107/service-accessing-a-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid a service that is continuously checking your DB for new records, you can use a broadcast message that tell something has changed. i.e. inside the function that store info in your database you can send your messsage.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Utils.REFRESH_DATA_INTENT));
```

And finally in your class you receive the message within an inner class.

```
    private class DataUpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Utils.REFRESH_DATA_INTENT)) {
            //Do whatever you need!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want @acostela is the same like when we check the check box under the Account & sync section and my sync adapter is called immediately .The same i want to do pro grammatically in my code .Whenever any entry to sq lite database made sync adapter should be called.I am looking for that lines of code.

Comment: Hi @Sandeepdhiman I used the above code to refresh a listview each time that a new record is stored in my DB or is updated. So I think you can extrapolate it to your solution. Try it and just tell me if you have any doubt